# Matching a Pantone Solid Coated colour with a Metallic Pantone perfectly?

Tags: pantone

I'm creating some packaging for a drinks company, I'm trying to match the flavour colour used on the bottle with the bottle cap which is metallic. The problem is i'm not getting a good match using pantone premium metallics. Just wondering if its possible to mix the flavour colour (Pantone 2995 C) with a Pantone Silver to get a perfect match? Any advice welcome...Thanks [image]

Comment: Did you try calling the printer? They have the best answer for sure. If I would be in this situation I will send a mail with exactly the same content of your question to the printer. The answers you can get here are hypothetical, knowing that then you will have to give that directive to the printer.

Comment: Yeah ive sent them some questions, i'm waiting for them to come back to me with some solutions, their in China though so just a waiting game....thanks for youre input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work very well.  You will probably be disappointed with the result.

Metallic litho inks aren't very shiny/lustrous to begin with. If you mix it with regular ink, you will reduce the lustrous effect even more.  Basically you'll dilute the metallic particles in the ink.

Perhaps look into another printing technology - such as hot foil printing.

Comment: Yeah spot on, thats what i was thinking, metallic are specifically mixed with flakes etc. Yeah foils could be the way to go...Kurz or foilco maybe, dunno if they have those in China though. hmmm.

Comment: Thanks for your'e reply...got me thinking about other options